# How can I change the value of the onclick attribute if the element has a particular class?

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement, onclick

I am looking for a solution if the element has an `active` `class`, can it change the `onclick` value to "closeSideBar"?

```js
function openSidebar() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('hamburger').style.marginLeft = '250px'
}

function closeSideBar() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('hamburger').style.marginLeft = '0'
}
```

```html
<button id="hamburger" onclick="openSidebar()">
```

I am looking for a solution to How can I achieve this result?

```
<button id="hamburger" onclick="closeSideBar()" class="active">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need a function `toggleSidebar`.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  const isActive = document.getElementById('hamburger').classList.contains('active');
  if (isActive) {
    closeSideBar();
  } else {
    openSidebar();
  }
}

function openSidebar() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('hamburger').style.marginLeft = '250px';
}

function closeSideBar() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('hamburger').style.marginLeft = '0';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to change the attribute value. You want to call just one function and direct its behavior.

Instead of separate open/close functions, use one:

```
function toggleSidebar(el) {
    if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = '0';
        document.getElementById('hamburger').style.marginLeft = '0'
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = '250px';
        document.getElementById('hamburger').style.marginLeft = '250px'
    }
}
```

Then call the function, passing the element:

```
<button id="hamburger" onclick="toggleSidebar(this)" class="active">
```

Protip: Don't manipulate styles directly. Instead, toggle classes so you can change sidebar size and position in one place, in your stylesheet:

```
function toggleSidebar(el) {
    if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
        document.body.classList.remove('sidebar-in');
    } else {
        document.body.classList.add('sidebar-in');
    }
}
```

Now you can set up your styles using descendant selectors:

```
body .sidebar { ... }
body.sidebar-in .sidebar { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that, but it's an anti-pattern. First, let me describe how you can achieve this:

```
function hamburger(active) {
    var myHamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
    myHamburger.classList[active ? "add" : "remove"]("active");
    myHamburger.onclick = (active ? "open" : "close") + "Sidebar()";
}
```

Now that you see how this works, look at the more elegant solution:

```
function openClose(item) {
    if (item.classList.contains("active"))  openSidebar();
    else closeSidebar();
}
```

and use this in your tag:

```
<button id="hamburger" onclick="openClose()">
```

Comment: Assuming IE isn't a concern you could use `myHamburger.classList.toggle("active")`

Answer (score 1):

Although an alternative solution wasn't asked for its worth considering a CSS only solution such as this:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
body {overflow-x: hidden; padding:40px; background: rgb(180,200,220);}

/* #nav-trigger is a hidden input */
#nav-trigger {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    visibility:hidden;
}

/* The nav itself (off-screen by default) */
#nav {
    width: 300px;
    max-width:80%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:-300px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    list-style: none;
    background: #111; 
}
#nav label.burger {
    width:30px; 
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right:-60px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
#nav ul a {color:#ffffff;}

/* animate the transitions */
#nav {
    -webkit-transition: right 0.2s, left 0.2s, margin 0.2s, background 0.2s;
    transition: right 0.2s, left 0.2s, margin 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}

/* move if nav-trigger is checked */
#nav-trigger:checked ~ #nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />

<div id="nav">
    <label class="burger" for="nav-trigger">&#9776</label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This Thing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Thing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something Else</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```